# Why is Esperanto popular in Iran?

Tags: history

Is there a reason why Esperanto is a lot more popular in Iran, compared to some countries like Arab countries in the Middle East and North Africa?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently it was promoted after the Iranian revolution in 1979:

> Ayatollah Khomeini of Iran called on Muslims to learn Esperanto and praised its use as a medium for better understanding among peoples of different religious backgrounds. After he suggested that Esperanto replace English as an international lingua franca, it began to be used in the seminaries of Qom. An Esperanto translation of the Qur'an was published by the state shortly thereafter. In 1981, its usage became less popular when it became apparent that followers of the Bahá'í Faith were interested in it.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto#Islam)

Comment: It is quite ironic, however, that it was praised for better understanding *among peoples of different religious backgrounds*, and then is dropped when that actually happens...!

Answer (score 1):

[What if Iran's proposal to the League of Nations in 1922 that everybody teach Esperanto in schools had been passed?](https://www.reddit.com/r/HistoryWhatIf/comments/4td5kp/what_if_irans_proposal_to_the_league_of_nations/)

Comment: This should really be a separate question; Stackoverflow is not the place for longer discussions, but just for questions and their answers.

Comment: Hello Oliver. your answer to this question is not correct. because you miss first Revolution of Iran (Persian Constitutional Revolution). also you miss Pahlavi period actually they were interested about Esperanto.